ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (tiktoken)
I am trying to install langchain_openai in my local machine with the python version 3.9
using pip
i passed below command:
pip install langchain_openai

I am getting below error
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (tiktoken)

i was able to install langchain in the system, but this causing the error..

Hello, did you have the tiktoken library already installed before you tried installing langchain ?

Hi @Lrx, i tried to install tiktoken, but still getting the same error as seen below
Failed to build tiktoken
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (tiktoken)

the most probable reason imo is linked with your python version. I'd suggest updating it to AT LEAST 3.10, even though 3.12 would be better.

Did you try pip install langchain-openai? Use a hyphen instead of an underscore. Also what environment are you running on?

uninstall the current version of langchain-core
and install
langchain-core-0.3.18 langchain_openai-0.2.8 tiktoken-0.8.0

